# Scrollbar for parent containing absolutely positioned element

Tags: css

I have the following code [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cebuh/1). Is it possible to have vertical scroll when messages overflow the wrapper? Thanks!

Comment: Is it must that first message comes up at the bottom?

Comment: Please expand a little. Just explain what you want to happen a little less terse. Also, it appears to do nothing in chrome.

Comment: I want the messages appear at the bottom and when they overflows the container a scrollbar should appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace your css with this css [demo](http://jsbin.com/kuvidodo/1)

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#list {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.message {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px;  
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: So you just added max-height. Great! Thanks!